# Service discoverability within openshift container platform

Tags: openshift

I am seeing different ways of service discoverability in openshift container platform.

1.We need to create service and then communincate using service IP/PORT

2. Using openshift DNS
3. Somewhere i read about multicast
4. Now service mesh.

I am not clear on how they are related and when to use what. Can anyone help me out here.

Comment: How about `oc get svc` or its equivalent in the API?

Comment: Not able to get you. Can you please elaborate more on it

Comment: I've posted an answer with a bit more detail. Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you issue the command `oc get svc` it will list services in your project, i.e. allow you to discover them. By default, it lists these service properties: `NAME`, `TYPE`, `CLUSTER-IP`, `EXTERNAL-IP`, `PORT(S)`, `AGE`. More detailed information and a REST interface for obtaining it are available as well.